# Kafka Stream application in spring boot keeps growing indefinitely

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Initially I did a more complicated kstream application that did a lot of complexed stuff. Running over a longer amount of time with peaks of 1500 concurrent users I saw that the container memory for the pod just kept on growing, even during nights where the load was very low 10-20 concurrent users.

So I started digging in the code for memory leaks, did all tweaks I could to improve the code. Nothing really helped except improved the performance. So what I did was create a simple spring boot application which basically listens to a topic and then just filter out some of the events and sends it to another topic.

```
public static KStreamBuilder evenNumbersTopology(KStreamBuilder builder) {    

        KStream<String, Integer> kStreamTest = builder.stream(stringSerde, integerSerde, INPUT_TOPIC);

        kStreamTest
            .filter((k, v) -> filterOutUnevenNumbers(v))
            .to(DESTINATION_TOPIC);

        return builder;
    }
```

Basically ran it for 2 weeks on a performance test that varied the concurrent users from 0-2000.
The memory kept on growing but stabilised from time to time. Can someone explain to me what's going on? I'm not storing anything I'm just streaming all events to a new topic basically.

Edit: The versions I'm using is:
Java 8

kafka version: 2.2.0 
Spring Boot: 2.1.0.RELEASE

Here some graphs from JVM: 
Note that the Tenured/Eden/Survivor space is only around 15 hours since I restarted everything. 

Tenured - this will drop when it reaches 64mb
[image: Tenured]

Survivor
[image: Survivor]

Eden
[image: Eden]

Also the container memory:[image]

Comment: can you add some more information about versions (kafka clients, spring, java)? Is your GC running correctly? I think the fastest way to determine what is going wrong with your memory is by using a profiler.

Comment: Edited my post about the versions. Also GC seem to work fine, I've been monitoring that in Grafana as well. ill add some results from those as well

Comment: Interesting... The inflection points are when the GC starts collecting for the Tenured Generation. Eden collection happens more frequently than the others and that's why it's all spiky. I guess that all the messages that are passing through the application are not freed from the memory. Can you post the full code, including the configuration? Or even better, can you create an example github repository?

Comment: It's not much more than the code snippet u see, but I can upload the Kafka streams configurations. Maybe the Dockerfiles as well?

Comment: It is quite interesting, cause I have observed the same memory behaviour even within the spring kafka application that wasn't processing anything for few days.

Memory dumps suggested that it might be related to new kafka metrics instances being generated all the time, but I coudn't find specific root cause too...